# How to undo "this.onclick=null"? How to restore javascript onclick functionality to a div?

Tags: javascript, html, css, null, onclick

I am displaying a div with a default background color. When I click it once, it changes color. A second click does nothing, because the div has this code: "this.onclick=null". That much works well.

However, after I click the div once, I want to click a button to restore its onclick functionality. But the button I have created for that purpose doesn't work, because I don't know what javascript code to use. Does anyone know?

As you can see, I'm working with Bootstrap 3. (Please note that I am a beginner with only basic knowledge of php and js.) Here is my code:

HTML for the div:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm-12">
    <div id="testDiv" style="background-color: #0000FF" onclick="colorClick(id); this.onclick=null;">
      Clicking this div once changes the color.
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

JAVASCRIPT for the div:

```
function colorClick(id){
var randomColor = '#'+Math.floor(Math.random()*16777215).toString(16);   
document.getElementById(id).style.backgroundColor=randomColor;

/* The random color generator is from stackoverflow.com/questions/1484506/random-color-generator */
}
```

HTML for the button:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm-12">
        <button type='button' class='btn btn-default btn-lg' onclick=reEnableOnclick()>
      This button should re-enable the onclick functionality, but it does not
    </button>
  </div>
</div>
```

JAVASCRIPT for the button:

```
function reEnableOnclick(){
document.getElementById("testDiv").onclick=click;  /* This is only pseudo-code. What real code should I put here? */
}
```

(Both js functions are in a separate .js document)

EDIT #2: This needs to work for about 100 divs on the same page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you need to apply this functionality to 100s of divs, try keeping track of just the locked states rather than all the divs states at all times. Assuming each div id is unique you could try:

**Javascript:**

```
    let locked = [];

    function lockCheckRun(id) { 
        let divID = document.getElementById(id);    
        if (!locked.includes(divID) {
            colorClick(id);
            locked.push(divID);
        }
    }

    function lockReset() {
        locked.length = 0;
    }
```

**Explanation:**

1. create an empty array to store locked element ids. We'll call this array 'locked'.
2. next, create a function which checks to see if the locked array includes the current unique element id. if it does not, then we will run your 'colorClick' function. once that completes, we will add the current element id to the 'locked' array via .push()
3. when you want to reset your locked element array, run the 'lockReset' function.

***Optional Polyfill for comptability with older browsers:***

```
    if (!String.prototype.includes) {
        String.prototype.includes = function(search, start) {
          'use strict';

          if (search instanceof RegExp) {
            throw TypeError('first argument must not be a RegExp');
          } 
          if (start === undefined) { start = 0; }
          return this.indexOf(search, start) !== -1;
        };
      }
```

Comment: Several good solutions have been given already, but this is the most useful so far, because it allows numerous divs to be locked individually, using an array that is as small as possible. The divs all get unlocked together, but that's okay, because it works for my purposes. This solution is also explained very well, and I was able to implement it successfully with few modifications. Thanks to everybody for all the good ideas.

Answer (score 1):

Assign the original `onclick` code.

```
function reEnableOnclick() {
    document.getElementById("testDiv").onclick = "colorClick(id); this.onclick=null;";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can have a pseudo variable inside your javascript code that serves the purpose

In this case you can write

HTML Code

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm-12">
    <div id="testDiv" style="background-color: #0000FF" onclick="colorClick(id)">
      Clicking this div once changes the color.
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm-12">
        <button type='button' class='btn btn-default btn-lg' onclick=reEnableOnclick()>
      This button should re-enable the onclick functionality, but it does not
    </button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Javascript Code

```
var divDisabled = false;

function colorClick(id){
 if(!divDisabled) {
  var randomColor = '#'+Math.floor(Math.random()*16777215).toString(16);   
  document.getElementById(id).style.backgroundColor=randomColor;
  divDisabled = true;
  /* The random color generator is from stackoverflow.com/questions/1484506/random- 
  color-generator */
 }
}

function reEnableOnclick(){
  divDisabled = false;
}
```

So now, You will set divDisabled for false by default so the first click of div will work as you want & following clicks on div won't as it is currently,

But As soon as you hit the button click it enables the click on div with setting buttonDisable to false, so it will again work once on div, as you want

Comment: Thanks to everyone for the suggestions and solutions. @Sarfraaz Now that I'm trying to implement this, I see a problem: I would typically need to apply this to about 100 divs all on the same page. So instead of starting with a single "var divDisabled = false;" statement, I'd have to iterate through 100 numbered divDisabled variables, setting them all to false. I could do that, but it would create a large array. Is there a more elegant solution?

Comment: Do you use jquery ? also, please share your html code with 2 divs & buttons so I can understand your html structure & suggest a solution according to same

Answer (score 1):

Don't remove the click event, just check a flag to see if the *behaviour* is enabled or not. E.G:

```js
var clickEnabled = true;

function colorClick(id) {
  if (clickEnabled) {
    var randomColor = '#' + Math.floor(Math.random() * 16777215).toString(16);
    document.getElementById(id).style.backgroundColor = randomColor;
    clickEnabled = false;
  }
}

function reEnableOnclick() {
  clickEnabled = true;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm-12">
    <div id="testDiv" style="background-color: #0000FF" onclick="colorClick(id);">
      Clicking this div once changes the color.
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm-12">
    <button type='button' class='btn btn-default btn-lg' onclick=reEnableOnclick()>
      This button will re-enable the onclick functionality
    </button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could define the function to run `onclick` outside of the assignment and use it to set and reset the click handler...

```
function functionThatRunsWhenButtonClicked() {
    // do stuff
}
```

then in the places you need to assign it, assign it..

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm-12">
    <div id="testDiv" style="background-color: #0000FF" onclick="functionThatRunsWhenButtonClicked(); this.onclick=null;">
      Clicking this div once changes the color.
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

function reEnableOnclick(){
    document.getElementById("testDiv").onclick=functionThatRunsWhenButtonClicked;  /* This 
    is only pseudo-code. What real code should I put here? */
}
```

You can do the same thing with `colorClick(id)`